# Why is a matrix non-invertible if its row-reduced echelon form matrix is not identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

I've been told that a matrix cannot be inverted if its row-reduced echelon matrix is not equal to the identity matrix. This is obvious to me in the sense that it cannot then be a valid solution to **A**x = **b**, but other than that, is there any other reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Because its row rank is not the maximal rank (the dimension of the matrix), hence its column rank is not either, so its column vectors are not a basis of the vector space.

Because its determinant is $0$.